# multiple mysql queries with different result names

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries from the same table and selecting the same info but sending results to two names. There are two variables to store the result, but how do I store other information from the queries?

```
require_once('connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to server, line 20.');
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id)  FROM artwork"; //find total number of id's
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or die("query error, line 22");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
find_pic(); //get the two id numbers
while ($count1 = $count2 or name = ""){ //problem line. check if counts = each other or either name = nothing
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
while ($count1=37 or $count2=37){ //if either count = 37
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
show_pic();

function find_pic(){
    $count1 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $count2 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count1";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count2";
    $result1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query1) or die("query error, line 38");
    $result2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query2) or die("query error, line 39");
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should note that `while ($count1 = $count2 or name = "")` is an inifinite loop as long as $name is not "".

Comment: Too confusing. It seems like a loop that ends when `$count2` equals `0`, but the part `name = ""` is not valid php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whole point is to get two random pictures why not do this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    artwork
WHERE 
    id != 37 AND
    name != ''
ORDER BY 
    RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: You are correct in me just getting two random pictures from my database. I am assuming != is not equal. Can I have WHERE id != 37 and name != ""? That would save me from doing a later test and rerunning function. Cool.

Comment: I am going to work on this later today. It looks like I will be able to get rid of quite a bit of code, just by asking for only the info I care about. Thank you, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it isnt complete solution for your problem, its only help):

```
$result1 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count1");
$result2 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count2");
$result1->execute();
$result2->execute();
$result1->bind_result($column1, $column2);   //all columns from table artwork
$result2->bind_result($column1, $column2);   //...


while ($result1->fetch())
{
    echo $column1;                       //here u have your result data
        echo $column2;

};
```

Learn how to use PREPARED STATEMENTS!!!! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: You're not really using prepared statements in your example, at least not in a way that shows how it's done properly.

Comment: I didnt say that im using prepared statements, that is the reason why i set here link.

Answer (score 0):

**1. You're assigning rather than comparing**:

```
while ($count1 = $count2 or name = ""){ //problem line. check if counts = each other or either name = nothing
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
while ($count1=37 or $count2=37){ //if either count = 37
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
```

Notice the single `=`s? You want two (or three):

```
while ($count1 == $count2 or name == ""){ //problem line. check if counts = each other or either name = nothing
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
while ($count1==37 or $count2==37){ //if either count = 37
    find_pic(); //if true, run function again
}
```

It's for this reason that I prefer to do `'' == $name` rather than `$name == ''` as `'' = $name` will result in a parse error which is better than a running but broken script.

**2. You're not passing `$row` to `find_pic()`:**

Most variables are subject to scope. `$row` doesn't exist inside the `find_pic` function unless you pass it as a parameter:

```
function find_pic($row){
    $count1 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $count2 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count1";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count2";
    $result1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query1) or die("query error, line 38");
    $result2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query2) or die("query error, line 39");
}

find_pic($row);
```

**3. `$count1` and `$count2` are not defined**:

You're setting them inside the `find_pic` function but they don't exist outside that scope. You might want to use references:

```
function find_pic($row, &$count1, &$count2){
    $count1 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $count2 = rand(0,$row[0]);
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count1";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE id = $count2";
    $result1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query1) or die("query error, line 38");
    $result2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query2) or die("query error, line 39");
}

find_pic($row, $count1, $count2);
```